# Export SSRS report along with drilldown

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that has a drilldown sub-report. How can I include the drilldown subreports along with the main report when exporting to PDF? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When exporting report into PDF, if you want to display the subreport, you can only expand the subreport part and then export. I don't think there's any workaround on this goal because the render behavior of PDF file is just like a snapshot of the report. And in PDF, there's no function which support expand/collapse page or part of context within a page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

=iif(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="PDF",FALSE,TRUE)

This may be helpful- http://www.techbrothersit.com/2015/10/ssrs-tutorial-part-124-export-ssrs.html